# Android : Location.distanceTo not working correctly?

Tags: android, location, distance

I am having an issue calculating distance using the `Location.distanceTo` method.

```
private class MyLocationOverlay1 extends MyLocationOverlay {
    @Override
    public void drawMyLocation(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, Location lastFix, GeoPoint myLocation, long when) 
        super.drawMyLocation(canvas,mapView,lastFix,myLocation,when);

        Location bLocation = new Location("reverseGeocoded");
        bLocation.setLatitude(FindList.gpslat);           // Value = 3.294391E7
        bLocation.setLongitude(FindList.gpslong);         // Value = -9.6564615E7
        Location aLocation = new Location("reverseGeocoded");
        aLocation.setLatitude(myLocation.getLatitudeE6());   // Value = 3.2946164E7
        aLocation.setLongitude(myLocation.getLongitudeE6()); // Value = -9.6505141E7
        aLocation.set(aLocation);    // Don't think I need this   
        bLocation.set(bLocation);    // Don't think I need this either

        int distance = (int)aLocation.distanceTo(bLocation);  // Value = 12637795 ???
        String str = " (" + String.valueOf(distance) + " meters)";
    }
}
```

Can someone tell my why my distance calculation is showing 12,637,795 Meters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should Modify lines:

```
aLocation.setLatitude(myLocation.getLatitudeE6() / 1e6);
aLocation.setLongitude(myLocation.getLongitudeE6() / 1e6);
```

And remove the lines:

```
aLocation.set(aLocation);
bLocation.set(bLocation);
```

Comment: Thank you, Looks like I have had some issues on some other things (reverse geocoding) that has been because of this.