# distanceTo() return distance not in meters !

Tags: android, gps, location, coordinates, distance

I am implementing an application to search for nearest local venues from a gps coordinates database.

i am using the Location class `distanceTo()` function to calculate distance between two location the current one and the one from the database.

```
currentloc.setLatitude(loc.getLatitude());
currentloc.setLongitude(loc.getLongitude());

dbcurrent.setLatitude(C.getDouble(latindex));
dbcurrent.setLongitude(C.getDouble(lonindex));
distance = currentloc.distanceTo(dbcurrent);
```

this work fine and i am able to use this distance to calculate proximity in the rest of my app, but the distance it self is not apparently in meters i am getting result like 4134801.4 i am sure that the distance is 3200meters in this case.

Is there any explanation or solution for this issue.

thank you all.

Comment: First double check your values to guarantee they are correct. Then make a test call where you get distance for maybe one second of longitude difference. See what happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : Location.distanceTo not working correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531324/android-location-distanceto-not-working-correctly)

Comment: Wondering how that other duplicate question was possibly missed in the review of existing questions the SO does before you ask?

Answer (score 0):

`distanceTo()` work correctly, it is your fault.
Such high distances can happen if your provide (0,0) as other point.